# Program to solve three simultaneous non-linear equations

Tags: math

I need to do some logistic regressions by hand as an assignment. In case you are not familiar with them, the formula is the following:

```
$N(t) = \frac{c}{1+ae^{-bt}}$
```

Do you know any software where I can add the above formula and the data points and then have an estimate for the `a`, `b` and `c` variables?